# How to pin footer to the bottom of page?

Tags: html, django-templates, footer

I tested many codes to pin the footer on the bottom of the page **but** none of them worked.
This is my footer tag:

```html
<footer class="container py-5  navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

And the div after that:

```html
 <div class="row" style="height: 100%">
```

What's wrong? Why it didn't work?
**Emergency question: please help**
*I'm working with Django(If that helps)*

Comment: There is too little information to help. What is your expected result? Are you using Bootstrap 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say with only these few lines of code but if you're using bootstrap 4 with Django then the bootstrap classes to fix the navbar to the bottom would usually be class="navbar fixed-bottom" but you could also use css to do this:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tnx, I will test. do you know why the footer didn't stick on the bottom with that code?

Comment: Can't say without seeing more code - as a rule when posting here, try to include whole blocks of code with html and css so that people can see the bigger picture. If your footer is contained within another div for example that div may control the position, or if there is another line of css being applied to the footer then that could over-ride any styles you are trying to apply. Also, if you're using any frameworks like bootstrap then include that info too as that will have a bearing on any errors and also the advice you will be given.

Comment: thanks, .that code you give helped :))) NOW I have another question,@Matt Reynolds; width of the footer isn't moz-available. I will ask that in my questions; hope to learn why...thank you again.

Comment: OF COURSE.I did